# What does it mean to be "British-French-American"?

Tags: meaning, hyphenation

On the Wikipedia page for [Les Misérables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables_(2012_film)) the first sentence says:

> Les Misérables is a 2012 **British-French-American** musical drama film . . .

What exactly does this double hyphenation imply?

Comment: It means that there are contributions from all three countries.  The book, of course, is French, the original opera was in French, as I understand it, but was reworked into English by people in the UK, and then the opera was brought to the US where it was eventually turned into a movie.

Comment: Comments removed. If you know the answer about the hyphenated nationalities which the OP asked about, please write one. Please don't argue in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly does this mean?

It purports to mean that the film was produced jointly by British, French and American producers. However, this is a mistake, as you can see in the immediately following sentence:

> The film is a British and American venture produced by Relativity
>   Media, Working Title Films and Cameron Mackintosh Ltd. and distributed
>   by Universal Pictures.

With regard to rules for determining a film's country of origin, see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_of_origin#Film_and_television_production

---

### Added:

The Wikipedia [manual of style for film-related articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Film) states:

> The lead section should introduce the film and provide a summary of
>   the most important aspects of the film from the article body. […] If
>   the film's nationality is singularly defined by reliable sources
>   (e.g., being called an American film), it should be identified in the
>   opening sentence.

Since the film's country of origin can be easily retrieved from a reliable source (and clearly were, as is evident from the next sentence and the footnotes to the article), labeling it as French in addition to British and American is obviously a mistake - not only by my standards, but also by Wikipedia's.

For those who wanted to read something into the difference between the opening sentence and the one following it, read on:

> If the nationality is not singular, cover the different national
>   interests later in the lead section.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46550/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-hor257k-what-does-it-mean-to-be-british-french).

Answer (score 2):

It just means that people, production companies or just locations from these countries were involved. Also keep in mind that it's Wikipedia, a *community created* encyclopedia. Anything you read there is not necessarily vetted.

As the article tells you the film has been filmed in France and England, with money and know-how from production companies from the US and England. It's based on a French musical in turn based on a French book. All the music is from a French composer. These facts led the *(random)* person who wrote the Wikipedia article to attribute the film to the three countries.

The next sentence clearly states it being a *British and American venture*. While I can only speculate on the motivations of the author, the first sentence might be an explicit means of emphasizing the French contribution to the overall film. After all, what's a musical without music?

Comment: Please take notice of:  http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32818618#32818618  --- **To the moderator:** A comment that points out a fact that contradicts the given answer is relevant and should not be deleted.